# Translate the following query in spring boot jooq query builder

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.name, t3.name) as name FROM table1 as t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN table2 as t3 ON t1.id2 = t3.id2
```

So I want to translate the above into jooq query builder! I did the following, but not sure if that is right or not:

```
dbReader.select(
t.name
).from(table1).leftJoin(table2).on(table2.id.eq(table1.id).or(table2.id2.eq(table1.id2))
```

something like that...
Is that correct? Or there is a better way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the [code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). In that case, the translation should be straightforward. Just declare [aliased tables](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/aliased-tables/) up front:

```java
Table1 t1 = TABLE1.as("t1");
Table2 t2 = TABLE2.as("t2");
Table2 t3 = TABLE2.as("t3");

ctx.select(coalesce(t2.name, t3.name).as("name"))
   .from(t1)
   .leftJoin(t2).on(t1.id.eq(t2.id))
   .leftJoin(t3).on(t1.id2.eq(t3.id2))
   .fetch();
```

This is assuming the usual static imports:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static com.example.generated.Tables.*;
```

Comment: Can I generate different pointers to the same table? Like the following:

Table t1 = TABLE1.as("t1");
Table t2 = TABLE1.as("t2");

Comment: @HassanShaitou: I'm not sure what you mean, but I had a typo in my answer, which is now fixed. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for that Lukas, what I mean is this from the jooq aliasing documentation (As you can see in the above example, calling as() on generated tables returns an object of the same type as the table). 
Like this: 
Table t1 = TABLE1.as("t1");
Table t11 = TABLE1.as("t2"); 

I am referencing same table with different aliases, does that means I can t1.<column> will have a different pointer than t11.<column>

Comment: anyways you answered my question thanks a lot Lukas

Comment: @HassanShaitou: Yes, I mean, that's the whole point of aliasing, isn't it? To alias the table and get renamed table *and* column references...